# Information/references/examples on fields $\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb C^3$ with divergence and curl free real and imaginary parts

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, terminology, vector-analysis, vector-fields

In the course of some physical considerations I came across a complex vector field
$$ \mathbf u = \mathbf v + i \mathbf w,  $$ with
\begin{align}
\mathbf v:& \mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^3\\
\mathbf w:& \mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^3
\end{align}

and the special propert, that it has a divergence-free imaginary and
curl free real components, that means

\begin{align}
 \vec{\nabla}\times \mathbf v & = \mathbf 0 \tag{1}\\
 \vec{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf w & = 0 \tag{2}
\end{align}

In my attempts to better understand and interpret the quantitiy described by this field, I started to wonder if:

> Question 1: This property has a special name/term in complex vector analysis.
>
> Question 2: If there are any important prominent examples of such fields.
>
> Question 3: If there are other properties that follow as a consequence of  (1) and (2).
>
> Question 4: If anyone can hint me at literature where such fields are investigated.

I would be very grateful for any hints at this. I would hope for answers like those to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401450/what-is-the-name-for-a-vector-field-that-is-both-divergence-free-and-curl-free).